# Passing information from one uwsgi request to another?

Tags: python, mysql, process, uwsgi, server-sent-events

I have a python application behind uwsgi running in ascync mode to support Server Sent Events (SSE). The application performs various tasks on a mysql database. On a SSE-connection I would like to be able to send events live as changes are being made to the database.

Ideally I would like to get notified when the datbase changes. Having searched for that I have not found any good solutions which doesn't include starting external proceses in a trigger. Since I don't want to introduce a big overhead on every change my current approach is instead to only report changes done by my application, not any other done in a mysql shell or similar.

The SSE-loop would look something like this:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response("200 OK", [('Content-Type', "text/event-stream")])

    while True:
        # wait for event somehow. using uwsgi.wait_fd_read()?

        # parse event from other uwsgi process

        # fetch new or updated data from database

        # generate SSE-event

        ev = ServerSentEvent()
        yield ev.encode()
```

And the other parts of the application, which modifies the database would be something like:

```
def changeDatabase():
    db.performQuery("update foo set .... ")

    # Send some event to other uwsgi processes that foo table has been updated
```

How can I do this? Signals? uwsgi signals? Shared memory? Writing to a file? Any other mechanism I'm unaware of? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i tend to use redis pub/sub for this sort of things. It is fast, reliable and easy to use. Basically your SSE app starts waiting on a pub/sub channel, and your django app publish to it. uWSGI signals are easy too but they do not carry some form of payload so they could be quite limiting.

Comment: Just to add more perspective: any [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) solution will do.